# Why is the Google Maps InfoWindowClick method executing twice on one click?

Tags: android, google-maps, methods, xamarin, infowindow

I am using Xamarin and am coding a Google Maps application. I have some code that executes when a user clicks on a Map InfoWindow. Here is the code:

```
void HandleInfoWindowClick (object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
{
    Toast.MakeText (this, "HandleInfoWindowClick", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
}
```

I set this handler up with the following code:

```
_map.MarkerClick += HandleMarkerClick;
```

Whenever I click on an InfoWindow, the method executes twice and the Toast is displayed twice as well.

Why is this? How can I fix this code such that the HandleInfoWindowClick method only executes once on a click?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about **HandleInfoWindowClick**, but here you have shown the event binding of **MarkerClick**.

You can try this:

```
_map.InfoWindowClick -= HandleInfoWindowClick; // first detach the handler if already attached
_map.InfoWindowClick += HandleInfoWindowClick;
```